# how to dynamically push form input inside object literal with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner in angular programming and i'm looking for some examples onhow to interact with object literal using this language. unfortunately, i didn't find any examples that could answer my questions about this topic.So, if i have this HTML file :

```html
<body ng-app="watch">
  

<div ng-controller="reely">
      <form>
        Name: 
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.name"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
        StreetAdress: 
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.streetAdress"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
        AddressLocality : 
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.addressLocality"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
        AddressRegion:
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.addressRegion"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
        postalCode :
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.postalCode"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
        AddressCountry:
        <input type="text" ng-model="place.addressCountry"  ng-change='change()'>
        <br/>
   Logo: <input type="text" ng-model="place.logo"  ng-change='change()'><br/>
   Url: <input type="text" ng-model="place.url"  ng-change='change()'><br/>
   Image:<input type="text" ng-model="place.image"  ng-change='change()'><br/>
      </form>
   <h1>
        Your JSON
      </h1>
      <p>
        {{mtl}} 
      </p>
    </div>
 
  
  </body>
```

If the user enters something in the different forms, datas will be automatically added to the object literal which look like this for example :

```html
{
  "@context": {
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "place",
      "@type": "schema:Person",
      "schema:name": " office",
      "schema:address": {
        "@type": "schema.PostalAddress",
        "streetAdress": "501 rue William",
        "addressLocality": "Toronto",
        "addressRegion": "ON",
        "postalCode": "H3C 1P4",
        "addressCountry": "CA"
      }
      "schema:logo": "http://active.com/images/logo.png",
      "schema:url": "http://shop.active.com/products/ra-r436",
      "schema:image": "http://active.com/images/ra-r4xx.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that datas should be displayed in different places inside the literal object.i know that that my post is not very clear and hope i could get a demo if possible

and this is my controller code :

```js
angular.module("watch", [])

.controller("reely", function($scope) {
    $scope.mtl = {
  "@context": {
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "place",
      "@type": "schema:Place",
     
      "schema:address": {
        "@type": "schema.PostalAddress"
       }
    }
  ]
}


    $scope.place = {};
 $scope.adress= {};
 
 $scope.adress["@type"]=  "schema.PostalAddress";
 
   
     function changeKeyValue() {

        for (var key in $scope.place) {
            if ($scope.place.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $scope.mtl["@graph"][0]["schema:address"]["schema:" + key] = $scope.place[key];
         
   }
        }
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        changeKeyValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and it also does not say at all what you have already tried. In your code where you have `Your JSON`, put `{{place}}` and you'll see your object literal populate as your type into fields.

Comment: Also, post your controller code.

Comment: but what i want is to fill the object literal by fulfilling the  style of the object that i put in my post

Comment: Ok what have you tried? Where is your controller code?

Comment: sorry i just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do it without almost any effort :) you can use another notation like this:

```
var obj={
    "@graph":[{
         "@type":"anyValueHere"
     }]
};
```

You can override values like this:
obj['@graph'][0]['streetAddress']="Toronto";

And as a result, you will get this new json object:

```
{
    "@graph":[{
         "@type":"anyValueHere",
         "streetAddress":"Toronto"
    }]
}
```

So based on this kind of notation, you can do that like this:

This is your html:

```
<div ng-controller="reely">
        <form>
            Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:name']" >
            <br/>
            StreetAdress:
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:address'].streetAdress" >
            <br/>
            AddressLocality :
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:address'].addressLocality" >
            <br/>
            AddressRegion:
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:address'].addressRegion" >
            <br/>
            postalCode :
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:address'].postalCode" >
            <br/>
            AddressCountry:
            <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:address'].addressCountry" >
            <br/>
             Logo:  <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:logo']" ><br/>
          Url: <input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:url']" ><br/>
          Image:<input type="text" ng-model="mtl['@graph'][0]['schema:image']" ><br/>
          </form>
          <h1>
            Your JSON
          </h1>
          <p>
            {{mtl}}
          </p>
    </div>
```

This will be your modified controller:

```
angular.module("watch", [])
.controller("reely", function($scope) {
    $scope.mtl = {
      "@context": {
         "schema": "http://schema.org/"
      },
      "@graph": [
        {
          "@id": "place",
          "@type": "schema:Place",
           "schema:address": {
            "@type": "schema.PostalAddress"
           }
        }
      ]
    };
})
```

As you can see, you use the "mtl" object directly from the html , just use the object["property"] notation.

So I hope it helps, and if it does, you can mark as the right answer :D